# Is this the best practice for SimpleDateFormat in spring boot?

Tags: spring, thread-safety, simpledateformat

The SimpleDateFormat is not a thread-safe class.

Is this the best practice to write a Utility Service for SimpleDateFormat in spring boot?

```
@Service
public class DateConvertUtil {

    private SimpleDateFormat getDateFormateInstance() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }

    public String parseDateToString(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = getDateFormateInstance();
        return sdf.format(date);
    }

    public Date parseStringToDate(String date) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = getDateFormateInstance();
        return sdf.parse(date);
    }

}
```

Comment: The best practice for `SimpleDateFormat` (Spring Boot or not), that’s very clear: **do not use it at all**. It is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. For handling and parsing dates use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Best practice is also to name your methods correctly to avoid confusion. *Parsing … is the process of analyzing a string of symbols* (from [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)). It’s not what your `parseDateToString` method does. Maybe `formatDateToString`?

Answer (score 0):

Base on my opinion :

- Annotation like `@Service` have the default scope is singleton.
- You do not contain any mutable state in the @Service, the problem of the thread-safe belong to the mutable state, which can be accessed between multiple thread and will make the system confused.
- Bonus : You can use @Configuration and @Bean for create bean for this Utils class.

> So I think it does not harm the system as well. Just try it and find the problem. Best practices require lots of practices

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have a faulty structure in your project .
Create a package Utill and put there all your classes or methods which you want to share in your project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).